# Sorting Categories Alphabetically in PHP

Tags: php

just wondering if someone knows a quick way to echo alphabetically- im echoing out categories and want to have them echoed out by name, alphabetically.. currently its by ID.

```
      <?php  //echo $categories; 
  foreach($categories as $category){
      echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="'.$category->id.'" id="category-'.$category->id.'">'.$category->name.'</button>';
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thank you

Comment: Where are you pulling categories from?

Comment: Taking a wild stab in the dark, I'm guessing you're getting them from a database, so try adding `ORDER BY name ASC` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution- thanks for the help;

where i got all the categories, used the order by :)
$this->db->order_by(‘name’, ‘asc’);